# Google Maps API v3 - Markers hiding behind OverlayImage

Tags: javascript, google-maps

In the past, Markers on this website appeared on top of the OverlayImage.  But now they seem to render behind the Overlay:

[Nashville Dining Map](http://www.nashvilledowntown.com/play/dining)

How do I impact the z-order of Markers vs. the OverlayImage itself?

Answer (score 0):

Markers seem to appear just fine, but you can set the markers z-index with setZIndex(zIndex:number) method.